# php jquery ajax for form validation but not for submit

Tags: php, ajax, forms, validation

Considering the following very basic form:

```
 <form action="action_page.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
   <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I know how to validate and submit this form using jquery ajax. My question: is there anyway I could first validate the form using ajax before submitting it the regular way to the action php file?

I mean the two processes should be the result of the submit action.. ie the script called should first validate and when all ok then submits the page to the file in the form action attribute or to any url I specify. Otherwise it halts form submit returning the error messages.

Thanks

Comment: The `submit` event listener uses `event.preventDefault()` and sends an AJAX request to validate it. The AJAX callback function submits the form if the validation is successful.

Comment: Ideally you should validate before sending the data to the server (if it can be validated locally), to prevent unnecessary requests to the server, and then validate on the server.

Comment: You can use jquery validation plugin and add a method with ajax validation for that.https://forum.jquery.com/topic/validation-plugin-addmethod-with-ajax

Answer (score 1):

This litle code works fine. If your ajax call is ok, then submit form. Is that the question?

Update your form (note type button in place of type submit)

```
<form name="action" id="action" action="action_page.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
   <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
   <input type="button" id="submit_button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And your js

```
$('#submit_button').on('click', function(e) {

  // Do your ajax call
  $.ajax({
    url:'myurl.php',
    type:'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      $('form').submit();// Finally submit
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert('Ajax error');
    }
  });
  
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p6xrm1d0/14/

Comment: Hi Monnomcjo, thanks for the reply but it didn't work. Even in my code editor when I type the "this." I get a huge list of autocomplete methods but "submit" is not one of them.

Comment: Welcome @techie2604, i updated my answer. It's ok now. Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript's `onsubmit` event.

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

and your js function will look something like this

```
function validateForm(){

 //perform all the validations and based on the validation return true or false.
 
 // you can use JQUERY within this to set the error divs or alerts etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks Danyal, Technically it works, but I don't want to put my validation code visible in the page source, this is why I am looking for a server-side ajax php validation then when it returns OK (code 200) then it continues submitting to the action php.